# Yii2 pagination

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

is it possible to use post id in pagination instead of page number
example instead of :

```
&page=2
```

it will be

```
&id=63
```

Pagination code is :

```
function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Article::find()->where(['status' => 1]);
    $countQuery = clone $query;
    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
    $models = $query->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
         'models' => $models,
         'pages' => $pages,
    ]);
}
```

view :

```
foreach ($models as $model) {
    // display $model here
}

// display pagination
echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
]);
```

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: I want to use pagination by id of content

Comment: @Bynd shortly yes, you can, but it's more complex and expensive operation. Why do you want it?

Comment: for images in content to pagginate by images id

Comment: then create pagination from images instead of Article.

Comment: Create Models from images and after applying pagination map images to article group for display purpose.